# Cognitive Service Recommendation API Upload Usage Event

Tags: recommendation-engine, azure-cognitive-services

Cognitive Service Recommendation API of Upload Usage Event method does not work well.

**Implementation Technique**

1. I was created in the order of the ”model” · ”catalog” · ”file” · ”build” in Cognitive Service Recommendation API.
2. Response of ”Upload Usage Event” is status code is successful in 201.
3. I call the ”Update model”.
4. I call ”Download usage file” and ”Get item to item recommendation”.
5. The item of ”Upload Usage Event” I tried to make sure it is reflected.
6. However, it did not reflect.

I want to know how to reflect the item of Upload Usage Event to Build.
Am I wrong what implementation procedure?

Answer (score 1):

After `[updloading a usage event][1]` you need to create a new build in that model for the usage event to be considered as part of the recommendations request.

Note that a single usage event may not significantly change the model. Usually you retrain the model once a week (or more or less depending on the level of traffic you receive) -- and at that point you would have had sent hundreds or thousands of usage events that may actually impact the model.