# Recommender API - Upload Usage Event

Tags: recommendation-engine, azure-cognitive-services

The documentation of this API is a little hard to understand in functional terms.
https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/Recommendations.V4.0/operations/577d91f77270320f24da2592

> Upload a usage event to a model. If buildId is set to "-1", the event
>   is ingested against the Active Build of the model. Set the buildId is
>   set to null or 0, the events are ingested against the Active build, if
>   Active build doesn't exist, the events are not associated with any
>   build.

"**is ingested against the Active Build of the model**"

- What does this mean?
- What happens when you associate events to a build?

I have been sending events using the Upload usage event API, but I don't see any changes on the active build on the Data Statistics tab.

Any help to understand this would be appreciated.

---

I'm building a batch process to send new usage events, and right now my approach is this:

1. Upload New Usage File
2. Delete Old Usage file
3. Create New Build
4. Change Active Build
5. Delete Old Build

I was hoping that the other API just to send users events would work, but since I can't make it to work as expected, I changed to this approach.

Is this a good approach or should be doing this in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

The upload usage file is a better approach than the upload usage event.

Reasons:

1. You get to send the events as one file thus decreasing your api usage count
2. You can always review and correct your usage files in case something is wrong. I do not see an api command to view/edit/delete uploaded events
3. You can reuse your usage files to recreate the model in case of an issue with the current one

Here is my own process during midnight:

1. Upload new usage file based on today's events
2. Create new build
3. Update my system to use new build number (since I have different build types in the same model)

Why this process?

Apparently, we will need to create a new build anyway for new usage data to be considered.

Per another post (answered by an authority on the subject)

> After [updloading a usage event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38847122/cognitive-service-recommendation-api-upload-usage-event?rq=1) you need to create a new build in
>   that model for the usage event to be considered as part of the
>   recommendations request.

You can check the whole post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38847122/cognitive-service-recommendation-api-upload-usage-event?rq=1)

Also, as mentioned in the linked post, a few usage events may not be enough to change the recommendations if done real time / frequently thus wasting effort. So a batch process, using usage files and done once per day is the more pragmatic approach.