# Build Id in Azure Recommendations API's Usage Event

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

From the documentation of 'Upload usage event' (https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/Recommendations.V4.0/operations/577ec1847270320f24da25b1), we can tie the event with the build id.

However, from [Cognitive Service Recommendation API Upload Usage Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38847122/cognitive-service-recommendation-api-upload-usage-event), it seems like I need to create a new build for the event to be considered. 
Is that still true? If that's the case, what is the purpose of sending the build id in the usage event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage events need to be tied to a particular model, not a particular build.

You will notice in the URL the location where the modelId is passed:
https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/recommendations/v4.0/models/{modelId}/usage/events

That just means that the next build you create for that model will take into consideration the new uploaded usage events. So, yes -- you do need to create a build after changing catalog and usage related information for that to be taken into consideration.

The only reason for the buildId to be passed as part of the usage event information is that it is helpful to get conversion metrics for a particular build.  (i.e. Since you would be notifying the system when a purchase actually occurs).

NOTE: Please notice that the recommendations API will be deprecated on Feb. 15 2018 -- therefore I would advise you to use The Recommendations Solutions Template (http://aka.ms/recopcs) instead.

Thanks!

Luis Cabrera | Program Manager | Recommendations Team

Comment: For the new Recommendations Solutions Template, I could not find the API to upload usage event. The new service seems to only accept usage CSV file. Could you please confirm this?

Comment: See answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48510241/usage-event-in-azure-recommendations-solutions-template/48510528#48510528