# Usage Event in Azure Recommendations Solutions Template

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

In the deprecated Recommendations API, there is an API to upload Usage Event. In the new Recommendations Solutions Template, I could not find that API call. The new service seems to only accept usage CSV file. Could someone please confirm this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mention, there is no API to upload a single usage event in the recommendations solution template (http://aka.ms/recopcs).

The workaround would be to open a file from blob storage (let's call it usageDelta.csv), add a line of content to it, and then write it back to blob-storage.

Note that you could create an "Append Blob" if you would like to do this efficiently. Here is a blog with someone doing something similar:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/thbrown/2015/08/26/azure-blob-now-has-append/

Thanks!

Luis Cabrera | 
PM - Recommendations API |
Cloud AI Platform